# Display a unique label for each facet in a forest plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am generating a forest plot to display the results of three simple linear regression models where the independent variable is categorical with four levels. I would like to report the overall p-value and the p-for-trend on each of the facets.

The data:

```
quantile = c('Qtile 1','Qtile 1','Qtile 1','Qtile 2','Qtile 2','Qtile 2','Qtile 3','Qtile 3','Qtile 3','Qtile 4','Qtile 4','Qtile 4')<br/>
estimate = c(1,1,1,1,2,3,2,4,5,3,4,5)
low95    = c(NA, NA, NA, .5, 1.5, 2.5, 1.5, 3.5, 4.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5)
high95   = c(NA, NA, NA, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 2.5, 4.5, 5.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5)
povarall = c(0.05, 0.06, 0.08, NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
ptrend   = c(0.04, 0.03, 0.06, NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
dv       = c('dv1', 'dv2', 'dv3','dv1', 'dv2', 'dv3','dv1', 'dv2', 'dv3','dv1', 'dv2', 'dv3')
df       = data.frame(quantile, estimate, low95, high95, povarall, ptrend, dv)
```

I attempted to use a text geom and specify the exact location for printing the p-values, but was unsuccessful.

This code :

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=estimate,y=quantile))+
   geom_point()+
   geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=low95,xmax=high95),height=0.0, colour="blue")+
   facet_grid(dv ~ .)+
   geom_text(x=5, y=1,label = paste("p =",df$povarall) , parse = F)
```

yields the following error: `Error: Incompatible lengths for set aesthetics: x, y, label`

The plot I would like is here (p-values added using Microsoft Paint):

[image]

Please let me know how I can adjust my code to get the image linked above.  It would be even better if I didn't have to specify the exact location of the text geom which should always be plotted in the lower right corner of each facet.

Comment: You need to put label inside the aes, just like your x and y values. You could also make a separate dataframe including x and y positions, because that makes dealing with the missings a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
df2 <- data.frame(p = paste('p =', povarall[1:3]), dv = c('dv1', 'dv2', 'dv3'))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = estimate, y = quantile)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = low95, xmax = high95), height=0.0, colour = "blue") +
  facet_grid(dv ~ .) +
  geom_text(data = df2, aes(label = p), x = 5, y = 1, parse = F)
```

[image]